# Iterate through arrays binded to keys (dynamic)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ngfor

Sample key-bound array

```
this.obj = { 
  key1 : [...],
  key2 : [...],
  .
  .
  keyn : [...] 
}
```

I have these 2 `*ngFor` loops where the key (above-mentioned keys) is used from outer `*ngFor` to define the inner `*ngFor`.

Say `keyVar` is the variable I get from outer-loop.
I tried implementing in the following ways but none worked.

```
*ngFor = "let item of obj.{{keyVar}}"
*ngFor = "let item of obj[keyVar]"
```

How do I implement it to work perfectly?

P.S: I'm using second `*ngFor` for `ng-options`. So, assigning a separate variable and calling from it doesn't work.

Comment: Not intending to be rude but I would recommend you avoiding labelling your question as "urgent": [[1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)] [[2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347983/introduce-an-urgent-tag)] [[3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/273150/has-there-been-any-discussion-for-allowing-urgent-bounties)] [[4](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6506/an-urgent-tag-for-questions-that-need-answers-within-minutes)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get keys from an object you could use the following function:

```
getKeys(): string[] {
  return Object.keys(this.obj);
}
```

And then in your component use it like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let key of getKeys()">
  {{key}}:
  <div *ngFor="let item of obj[key]">{{item}}</div>
</div>
```

Here is the [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hne6um)

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm. I tried using a function in ngFor but can't recollect why it failed.

Comment: @AkashChintha You're welcome! I was glad to help. A function could fail because _the string assigned to `*ngFor` is not a template expression. It's a microsyntax — a little language of its own that Angular interprets_. And I guess it can interpret only some basic constructions